# DataGridViewImageCell Images not displayed on Load, but displayed on Refresh

Tags: c#, datagridview, refresh

I have an `ImageColumn` on my `DataGridView` that acts according to another hidden cell called "HasWarnings". On form Load event I refresh this DataGridView so for each row, if `HasWarning` is true the warning image and otherwise a success image is displayed. I also have a *Refresh* button on top of my `DataGridView`.

However, the images are not displayed on `Form Load` event and I get the red cross image. It is only when I press on the Refresh button that they come back. What surprises me is that by clicking on the *Refresh* button the very same function as the Load event is called. Below is the code to the Refresh method that is called both on Load event and on the button click:

```
public void RefreshHistory()
{
    pnlOverview.Visible = false;
    pnlNoHistory.Visible = false;
    try
    {
       using (var db = new Entities(cs)
       {
         var linqHistory = db.Histories.Select(h => new 
            { h.Id, h.RunDate, h.HasWarnings }).OrderByDescending(h => h.RunDate).Take(500);
          if (linqHistory.Any())
          {
                dgvHistory.DataSource = linqHistory.ToList();
                dgvHistory.Columns["Id"].Visible = false;
                dgvHistory.Columns["HasWarnings"].Visible = false;
                dgvHistory.Columns["RunDate"].HeaderText = "Date/Time";
                pnlOverview.Visible = true;
                dgvHistory.Rows[0].Selected = true;
                long reportId = Convert.ToInt64(dgvHistory.Rows[0].Cells["Id"].Value);
                SetWarningImages();
                SetReportDetails(reportId);
            }
            else pnlNoHistory.Visible = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

And this is `SetWarningImages()` method that assigns the corresponding image to each row in the `DataGridView`:

```
private void SetWarningImages()
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvHistory.Rows)
    {
        bool hasWarnings = (bool)row.Cells["HasWarnings"].Value;
        if (hasWarnings)
            ((DataGridViewImageCell)row.Cells["HasWarningsImage"]).Value = 
                                              Properties.Resources.warning16;
        else
            ((DataGridViewImageCell)row.Cells["HasWarningsImage"]).Value =
                                               Properties.Resources.success16;
    }
}
```

I am wondering why this very code does not display the images (but the data is displayed correctly) on `Load` but works on the `button_click`?

**N.B.** Adding the lines `dgvHistory.Refresh();` or `dgvHistory.PerformLayout();` is not helping either.

Comment: Form load may be too early.. Would Layout work better?

Comment: @TaW That was correct! You can post it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [order of events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d.aspx) sometimes will force you to delay some things a little until the `Form` is Shown and its Layout fully complete.

Therefore it often helps to move a call to maybe the `Form.Shown` or `Form.Layout` events. Note that `Form.Layout` may happen [more often](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.layout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) than you like so `Form.Shown` is probably preferrable, unless you want to use a flag..

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005227/triggering-an-event-after-a-winform-layout-is-complete) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070163/order-of-events-form-load-form-shown-and-form-activated-in-windows-forms) post there are interesting discussions abut the topic..